# Horizontally center element a specific breakpoint and below

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

With bootstrap 4 I'd like to horizontally center an element such as a `<select>` within a `col`, at a given breakpoint and breakpoints **below** that. Using built-in bootstrap 4 utilities, not custom CSS, is this possible?

For example, center a `<select>` at xs and sm breakpoints, but return to the normal left align at md, lg, and xl.

Bootstrap has the utility `mx-sm-auto` but this centers the element at the sm breakpoint and **above**. Here's a codepen showing that: https://codepen.io/cpj22/pen/QWLZwJd

(**Note to editors**: I've searched the popular answers on SO, and all of them regard horizontally centering *inline* elements. If there is a duplicate please ensure it is for block elements, bootstrap 4 has different utilities for each)

Comment: What about adding a class "align-items-center" at row?

Comment: @GamersAgenda that will center at all breakpoints, won't it?

Comment: Since you're using auto margins you're really centering the entire column within the row, not the `select` inside the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is [built to be mobile-first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints), with all the built-in media queries based off of [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width). That means that you cannot easily create a selector that is *only* applied to the `xs` and `md` breakpoints (as there is no `xs`  utility size in Bootstrap 4).

However, you can *override* these mobile-first rules with *further* mobile-first rules targetting higher size breakpoints. Applying the class `ml-md-0` in addition to `mx-auto` will give a left-hand `margin` of `0` on any breakpoint that is at *least* `md`, while still *retaining* the desired `auto` `margin` for the `xs` and `sm` breakpoints.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.bg1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.bg2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 bg1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto ml-md-0">
          <select class="form-control mt-5 mb-5">
            <option>select one</option>
            <option>select two</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using auto margins (mx-auto) you're really centering the entire column within the row, not the select inside the column. As @ObsidianAge said, you can reset the column centering by setting the margins to 0..

```
     <div class="col-6 bg1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 mx-md-0 mx-auto">
                    <select class="form-control mt-5 mb-5">
                        <option>select one</option>
                        <option>select two</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

However, I don't understand the purpose of the nesting inner `col-6` inside the outer `col-6`. If the only purpose of the inner col-6 is to limit the width of the `form-control` it would be easier to use `w-50` for the input, and the responsive text alignment utils (`text-center text-md-left`). This way you're centering the select inside the column, not the column itself..

```
   <div class="col-6 bg1 text-center text-md-left">
        <select class="w-50 form-control d-inline mt-5 mb-5">
            <option>select one</option>
            <option>select two</option>
        </select>
   </div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/faoFpkh8Ij

Comment: That's a good point. In this specific case we need dramatically different widths at different breakpoints (col-12 and col-xl-3 for example), but your option is typically a good one

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this picture? use this code

[image]

```css
.bg{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, lightgrey 50%, lightblue 50%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, lightgrey 50%, lightblue 50%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 mx-sm-auto">
            <select class="form-control mt-5 mb-5">
              <option>select one</option>
              <option>select two</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   
  </body>
</html>
```